# Looking for a good exercise book of advanced probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm looking for a good exercise book for advanced probability theory. I would prefer if the book includes solutions (partially if not fully).

I would like the book to cover topics similar to: the content of  "Probability: Theory and Examples" by Durret and 'A Course in Probability Theory' by Kai Lai Chung.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try "Problems in Probability" by Shiryaev

Comment: It is a good book with several problems.   Though no solution for these exercises.  Do you know is there any solution manual for it?  Many thanks!